# Как изменить значения меток в файле jsonl на значения из списка прогнозов

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение

У меня есть такой файл `jsonl` и список прогнозов модели машинного обучения. Как изменить значения в метке на значения из прогнозов? Вот моя функция обработки, но ничего не происходит. Как я могу изменить свою функцию, чтобы заменить или написать новую функцию, а затем сохранить все в формате `jsonl`?

```
print(predictions) ## [0, 1, 0...0, 0, 0]

def get_answer(dic):
  for i in int_predictions:
    dic['label'] = 0
  return dic
import random
for i in tqdm(range(len(new_test))):
    q = new_test[i]['passage']['questions']
    for j in range(len(q)):
        #print(q[j])
        q[j]['answers'] = [get_answer(dic) for dic in q[j]['answers'] ]
    new_test[i]['passage']['questions'] = q
```

```
{'idx': 0,
 'passage': {'questions': [{'answers': [{'idx': 0, 'label': 0},
     {'idx': 1, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 2, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 3, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 0},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 4, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 5, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 6, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 7, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 1},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 8, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 9, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 10, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 11, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 2},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 12, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 13, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 14, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 15, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 3},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 16, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 17, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 18, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 19, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 20, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 4},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 21, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 22, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 23, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 24, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 25, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 5},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 26, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 27, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 28, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 29, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 30, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 6},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 31, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 32, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 33, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 34, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 35, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 7},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 36, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 37, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 38, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 39, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 40, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 8},
   {'answers': [{'idx': 41, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 42, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 43, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 44, 'label': 1},
     {'idx': 45, 'label': 1}],
    'idx': 9}]}}
```